# Remove everything from output till to defined var

Tags: bash, perl, awk, sed, grep

From ps command I want to have some var in that case "PS1" to be defined and after that everything till that var to be deleted.

ex.:

```
ps -ef | grep -i PS1
cbsuser 1138700       1   0   Sep 15      -  0:10 ./PS1 PS01 3
```

expected output:

```
./PS1 PS01 3
```

In my mind is something like which is wrong:

```
sed 's/^$/ "PS1"/g'
```

or related I'm not sure how to finish it.

Comment: ps -ef not always return the same structure (date and day depend from how long). PS1 could be also found in user name or argument of a process. PS1 could be started from several way/path). What could we assume for those case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ps -ef | perl -lne 'print $1 if /(\S* PS1 .*)/xi'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use custom format for `ps` to output only what you need so you only need to filter for the required command in the list:

```
ps e --format %a | grep PS1
```

Or even better use `pgrep` that is designed to do this if it's available:

```
pgrep -fl PS1 | cut -f2- -d' '
```

Answer (score 2):

A few options. These all parse your command. A better approach is to use `pgrep` or the `o` option for `ps` but if you really want to parse:

1. grep itself

   ```
   ps -ef | grep -Po 'PS1.*'
   ```
2. perl

   ```
   ps -ef | grep -i PS1 | perl -pe 's/.*(?=PS1)//'
   ```
3. sed

   ```
   ps -ef | sed 's/.*\(PS1.*\)/\1/'
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
ps -ef | grep -i PS1| awk '{ for(i=9;i<=NF;++i)printf "%s ",$i }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this,

```
ps -eo cmd | grep 'PS1'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ps -ef | grep -i PS1| grep -v grep| awk '{print $(NF-2)" "$(NF-1)" "$NF}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify with using `pgrep`:

```
 pgrep -fl PS1 | cut -d ' ' -f2-
```